# Parsing data makes my app crash--Why?

Tags: java, android

So I am making an app that takes data from a webpage as text, parses it into data structures, and then displays it in a table.  The trouble is, I wrote the code that creates the data structures and places the data in a table, but now, the app crashes when I run it.  Here is the relevant code:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String s1 = makeReadable(result);
        ArrayList <OfferRequest> al = makeStructures(s1);
        makeRows(al);
   }
}

public String makeReadable(String input){
    String result  = input.replace("~~", "[empty]");
    String result2  = result.replace("~", "");
    String result3  = result2.replace("<", "");
    String result4  = result3.replace(">", "");
    return result4;
}

public ArrayList <OfferRequest> makeStructures(String input){
    OfferRequest or;
    ArrayList <OfferRequest> orList = new ArrayList <OfferRequest>();
    String [] items = input.split ("\n");
    String [] splitItems;
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        splitItems = items[i].split("|");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(splitItems[0]);
        int isOffer = Integer.parseInt(splitItems[1]);
        boolean isOffer2 = (isOffer != 0);
        int units = Integer.parseInt(splitItems[2]);
        double price = Double.parseDouble(splitItems[3]);
        String currency = splitItems[4];
        String created = splitItems[5];
        String specs = splitItems[6];
        String comment = splitItems[7];
        String companyName = splitItems[8];
        String category = splitItems[9];
        String itemName = splitItems[10];
        String user = splitItems[11];
        String toBeDelivered = splitItems[12];
        String lastUpdated = splitItems[13];
        or = new OfferRequest(id, isOffer2, units, price, currency, created, specs, comment, companyName, category, itemName, user, toBeDelivered, lastUpdated);
        orList.add(or);
    }
    return orList;
}

public void makeRows(ArrayList <OfferRequest> input){
    TableRow t;
    TextView t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
        t1 = new TextView(this);
        t2 = new TextView(this);
        t3 = new TextView(this);
        t4 = new TextView(this);
        t5 = new TextView(this);
        t6 = new TextView(this);
        t7 = new TextView(this);
        t8 = new TextView(this);
        t1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t5.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t6.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t7.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t8.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t1.setText(input.get(i).getCategory());
        t2.setText(input.get(i).getItemName());
        t3.setText(Integer.toString(input.get(i).getUnits()));
        t4.setText(input.get(i).getCurrency());
        t5.setText(Double.toString(input.get(i).getPrice()));
        t6.setText(input.get(i).getUser());
        t7.setText("Unknown");
        t8.setText(input.get(i).getCreated());
        t = new TableRow(this);
        t.addView(t1);
        t.addView(t2);
        t.addView(t3);
        t.addView(t4);
        t.addView(t5);
        t.addView(t6);
        t.addView(t7);
        t.addView(t8);
        table.addView(t);
    }
}
```

Am I just overloading the device's processor or something?  The app ran, albeit slowly, when I just had it printing unformatted data in a table.

Here's the logcat stuff:

```
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.onegdd.orbit.MainActivity.makeStructures(MainActivity.java:263)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.onegdd.orbit.MainActivity.makeReadable(MainActivity.java:253)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.onegdd.orbit.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:203)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.onegdd.orbit.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-29 12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "the app crashes" is so vague we don't have any clue what is going on. Clarify what is going wrong by posting exceptions/logcat/ect...

Comment: And check for null value before `Integer.parseInt`. That might cause a problem if the value being parsed is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with 'overloading the processor', it's a data problem:

```
12:11:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1763): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

You're code will need to check for dodgy data if you want it to be robust.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Just one more thing though--is there a way to find out what the error is referring to?  The Logcat doesn't seem to say what data is invalid.

Comment: Tricky because you don't have much context of where the error is occuring (e.g. line numbers).  You do have the loop in your `makeStructures` method, so perhaps add a `try..catch` block around that to log the exception and the index counter, that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are getting .. `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Try like this if number is not in int format ...

```
Integer.parseInt(string);
```